# Google AdSense crawler unable to crawl my image-based website

Tags: google-adsense, web-crawlers

I have recently set up a website and applied for Google AdSense.

However my website is being not crawled properly. It is basically a image-based website with text under each image. It contains a lot of text but all of it is contained in the `<title>` tag and not the description.

Is this the problem?

Comment: You probably mean the title attribute, like this: <img title=".." src=""/>. <title> looks like a tag and not an attribute to me, this has someone edited though..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's one of them.

The `<title>` attribute provides "advisory information", and is not indexed by search engines. See this for more on that:  [W3C - The title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3)

In addition to the title attribute, you should be using the [alt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) attribute, as covered here:  [Matt Cutts Discusses the Importance of alt Tags](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NbuDpB_BTc&feature=youtu.be)

Google AdSense needs to be able to find content related to keywords. With a site solely made up of images and no other content, it's unlikely that you'll be approved. You should add text that can be read by visitors without hovering over images (as is the case with the above) so that AdSense can display ads related to the search terms that led to your site and the content contained on it.

In short, you should add HTML content, in addition to using `alt` text for images instead of just having title text.